# Vue CKEditor External Links

Tags: vue.js, ckeditor5

I am working on a Vue project which uses ckeditor in one component. 
I am trying to set up hyperlinks to open using target="blank" whenever an external link is detected.

According to the docs I am able to do this with an editorConfig object in the data property of the instance.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div @click="toggleEdit">
    <h3>Program Body</h3>
    <div v-if="!editing" v-html="active.body" />
    <ckeditor :config="editorConfig" :editor="editor" v-if="editing" v-model="form.body" />
    <div v-if="editing" class="row row__end padding__sm">
      <button class="btn btn__cancel" @click.stop="cancelUpdate">Cancel</button>
      <button class="btn btn__green" @click.stop="updateProgram">Update</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";
export default {
  props: ["active", "user"],
  data() {
    return {
      editor: ClassicEditor,
      editorConfig: {
        link: {
          addTargetToExternalLinks: true
        }
      },
      permissions: ["admin", "marketing"],
      editing: false,
      form: {
        formObject: "programs",
        formAction: "edit",
        _id: this.active._id,
        body: this.active.body
      }
    };
  },
```

I have confirmed that the ckeditor tag is using the config by altering some other properties, but it never adds any attributes to links starting with http:// or https://.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to update to the latest version of ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue. As this will have the fixes for your issue. For installation instructions visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue/v/1.0.1

Here is a simplified codepen to show this functionality working with version 1.0.1 https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue

https://codepen.io/twickstrom/pen/rNOGZYb

Visit the pen, highlight a word, add a link and view the source, voila! The _target attribute has been appended.

Here is the BASIC code.

Main JS

```
Vue.use(CKEditor);
```

Component

```
<ckeditor :editor="editor" v-model="editorData" :config="editorConfig"></ckeditor>

data: {
  editor: ClassicEditor,
  editorData: '<h1>Title</h1><p>Content of the editor.</p>',
  editorConfig: {
    link: {
      addTargetToExternalLinks: true
    }
  }
}
```

If after verifying the version you are still having problems I would strip out everything but the basics and start reading complexity until you find the culprit.

Comment: I don't have a custom configuration of ckeditor being used.  In main.js only have ```Vue.use(CKEditor)``` where CKEditor is @ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue.  Attempting to install the /src/link version of link does not work.  When using the @ckeditor/ckeditor5-link package, Webpack is unable to build because the module is not found.

Comment: @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic: ^11.2.0                @ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue:  ^1.0.0-beta.1

Comment: I am sure that your outdate versions are the issue try upgrading. As you can see by the working example above it is using ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue 1.0.1 https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue/releases this will pull in ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^16.0.0"

Comment: @BradChandler any luck?

Comment: I did update both packages, but the only which came through as anything different was the vue package.  Attempting to import the link package still said that it couldn't resolve @ckeditor/ckeditor5-link

Comment: Not sure what to tell you, as you can see from the very simplified example on codepen the latest version is working as expected. Try Manually updtating ckeditor to ^16.0.0 and make sure to check your main.js that you are calling Vue.use( CKEditor );

Comment: Said another way it has to be something in your specific build/app that is causing the issue. Try posting a simplified version on codepen for additional help.